# Not able to retrieve text from the textbox using webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am automating one of our client website, in there is one textbox, i just need to verify the whether the textbox is editable or not. For that, i am clicking on the textbox, entering the random string and again retrieving the text entered to check if same text is written or not.

I am successfully able to find, click and write in the textbox but when i retrieve the text it always return blank (or ""). Can you guys please tell me what the issue may be?

[image: Text Box description]

Comment: why don't you verify the text by using the method "verifyValue" instead of storeText?

Comment: C# WebDriver? Also show some code...

Comment: @pArAs: For just confirming that same was the case with selenium IDE,  i posted the screenshot of IDE. Anyhow i got the text via getAttribute("value"). Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can try this :

```
 findElement(By.id("someid")).getAttribute("value");
```